# Problema con string del correo

Tags: python, python-3.9

Necesito ayuda para verificar este codigo, Se conecta mediante pop3 al correo electronico desde python3 pero al leer los mensajes no descodifica el contenido del cuerpo, es decir, que lo tabulado no me devuelve un string de respuesta sino todo el cuerpo del correo con su codificacion.
como puedo arreglarlo?
Creo que el error esta aca

```
res, mensaje = mail.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
```

**Si alguien puede probarlo verificara el problema.**

```
import poplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import os
from getpass import getpass
from email.parser import Parser

# Conexion POP3 Outlook
mail = poplib.POP3_SSL('outlook.office365.com') 
mail.user('xxxx@outlook.es')
mail.pass_('******')


# Selecciono la casilla de entrada
# Inbox
mensajes = len(mail.list()[1])
print(mensajes)

# cantidad total de correos
email_stat = mail.stat()
mensajes = email_stat[0]

for i in range(mensajes):     
    for j in mail.retr(i+1)[1]:
        print(j)

# print(f"vamos por el mensaje: {i}")
 #   # Obtener el mensaje
    try:
         res, mensaje = mail.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
         # res, mensaje = mail.uidl(str(i), "(RFC822)") 
    except:
         break
    for respuesta in mensaje:
         if isinstance(respuesta, tuple):
             # Obtener el contenido
             mensaje = email.message_from_bytes(respuesta[1])
 #           # decodificar el contenido
             subject = decode_header(mensaje["Subject"])[0][0]
             if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                 # convertir a string
                 subject = subject.decode()
             # de donde viene el correo
             from_ = mensaje.get("From")
             print("Subject:", subject)
             print("From:", from_)
             print("Mensaje obtenido con exito")
 #           # correo html 
             if mensaje.is_multipart():
                 # Recorrer las partes del correo
                 for part in mensaje.walk():
                     # Extraer el contenido
                     content_type = part.get_content_type()
                     content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                     try:
                         # el cuerpo del correo
                         body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                     except:
                         pass
                     if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                         # Mostrar el cuerpo del correo
                         print(body)
                         body.remove() #remove() elimina en base al contenido
                         # mensaje.dele(i) #elimine un mensaje

mail.quit()
```

Comment: Cual es el error concreto que tienes? O solo quieres que revisen el código?

Comment: si, lo he terminado, pero al leer los datos del correo aparecen los datos sin descodificar.No logro identificar bien cual es el problema.

Comment: En ese caso, modificá el título tu pregunta: suena más bien a que querés que depuremos el código por vos. Pulsá en [edit] y escribí el problema en particular que estás teniendo: leé [ask].

Comment: Gracias, ya lo cambie. Espero que se entienda, el problema viene de que el mensaje no tira un resultado en string sino en codigos.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230571/236345), parecería que lo que almacenas en `mensaje` es más complejo de lo que pensabas

Para obtener el contenido en el body, pareciera que necesitas hacer

```
msg = email.message_from_string(mensaje[0][1])
```

Y msg tendría el contenido del body, sin los adjuntos.

Comment: Gracias, lo modifique pero el error sigue estando. Aparece de esta forma: b'=C2=A1Hola!'
b'<p>'
b'Te invito a que sumes tu nombre en esta petici=C3=B3n a trav=C3=A9s de tu f='
b'irma.'

Comment: @211w y antes te salía eso mismo? Es que ahí ya es sólo problema de decodificar el mensaje...

Comment: Claro, he probado varias alternativas y llego a la conclusion que es descodificar el mensaje, pero no le encuentro falla a las entradas ni a la sintaxis, por eso buscaba otras opinines. Probe de varias maneras agregando lo que me recomendaste pero sigue tirando el error :o